# jquerymobile. double execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have such code:

```js
function getData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://pechati.ru/extdata/baseparts/filialsWSunsec.php',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(jsonData){
            //alert('Load was performed.');
            console.debug('Data received.');
            //jsonData = win2unicode(jsonData);

            console.debug(jsonData);
            $.each(jsonData,function (filial,dataFilial) {
                //
                //console.debug(filial);

                var option = '<option value="'+filial+'" data-phone="'+ dataFilial.phone+ '" data-email="' + dataFilial.email + '"> ' + filial + '</option>';

                //filial active
                var activeFilial = 0;
                if (parseInt(dataFilial.mainList)>0){
                    activeFilial++;
                }
                if (parseInt(dataFilial.contacts)>0){
                    activeFilial++;
                }
                if (parseInt(dataFilial.uslugi)>0){
                    activeFilial++;
                }
                if (activeFilial>0){
                    $('#filial-name').append(option);
                }
            });

        },
        error: function(error){
            console.debug('We have a problem: ');

        }
    });
}

...
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {


    $('a.get-order').on('click', function () {
        getData();   
        
    });
}
```

getData is executing twice after click on **a.get-order** it. Why is happening it?
This is element  placed in :

```html
<div id="one">
...
</div>
<div id="two">
...
<a class="get-order">...</a>
</div>
```

The first page is loaded "#one". From it called page "#two". After click on **a.get-order** I have double execution getData(). If I am calling page "#three" from page "#two" and execute some function there it executed three times.
Why is it happening and how fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $('a.get-order').on('click', function () {
        getData();           
    });
}
```

Runs every time any page is initialized. So the click handler is added once when #one is initialized and then again when #two is initialized.  Change it to

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#two", function(){ 
    $('a.get-order').on('click', function () {
        getData();           
    });
});
```

This way the click handler is only added once when page #two is initialized.

Comment: I tryed $(document).on("pageinit","#two", function(){  but nothing changed. getData () is double executing.

Comment: @Skif, here is a working demo: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/bZPdPZ  can you edit it to reproduce your issue?